# How is the rate of convergence affected after a function transformation is applied?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Say we know that a sequence $x_t$ converges to $x$ at the rate $O(1/log t)$. Can I say at what rate $\exp(x_t)$ converges to $\exp(x)$ ?

It comes as a subproblem in my work, and honestly I have no idea how to proceed or where to look. The convergence criteria which I am getting from textbooks are not helpful. How do I solve this? and how do I become better at handling questions like these ?

Comment: Hint: use the derivative of the transformation at the limit.

Comment: Please Provide more information about your research and attempts at solving the problem. Also please refer to mathjax for writing mathematical expressions https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Based on Ian's reply:

$$\| x_t - x \| \sim O(\frac{1}{\log t}) \implies \| f(x_t) - f(x) \| \sim \|\nabla f(x)\| \| x_t - x\| \sim  \|\nabla f(x)\| \|  O(1/\log t) \implies  \| f(x_t) - f(x) \| \sim O( \frac{1}{ \log t}) $$

Is this correct? So, as long as the derivative at the limit is bounded, the rate is the same?? that seems wrong. Shouldnt the transformation lead to slower or faster rates?

Comment: Nope, it's just a constant factor, unless the transformation is not differentiable near the limit.